# How do I create a radio button that accept user input text?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm fairly new to this, but I was wondering how would I get the "Other" radio button to accept user input as a text field? I would like to give the user the option to customize their own delimeter. For instance, they may want the delimeter to be "><" or "//". Is this possible using PyQt?

[image]

Here is my code for the radio button group belonging to the Delimeter options.

```
    #Label for Delimeter options
    self.delimeter_option_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
    self.delimeter_option_label.setText("Delimeter Options")
    self.delimeter_option_label.setFont(MYFONT)
    self.delimeter_option_label.move(250,100)
    self.delimeter_option_label.adjustSize()

    #Delimeter option for "|" character
    self.delimeter_option1 = QRadioButton("|", self)
    self.delimeter_option1.move(250,125)
    self.delimeter_option1.resize(300,20)

    #Delimeter option for "," character
    self.delimeter_option2 = QRadioButton(",", self)
    self.delimeter_option2.move(250,150)
    self.delimeter_option2.resize(300,20)

    #Delimeter option for Tabs
    self.delimeter_option3 = QRadioButton("Tab", self)
    self.delimeter_option3.move(250,175)
    self.delimeter_option3.resize(300,20)

    #Delimeter option for custom delimeter
    self.delimeter_option4 = QRadioButton("Other", self)
    self.delimeter_option4.move(250,200)
    self.delimeter_option4.resize(300,20)

    #Groups Delimeter option buttons together
    box_group2 = QButtonGroup(self)
    box_group2.addButton(self.delimeter_option1)
    box_group2.addButton(self.delimeter_option2)
    box_group2.addButton(self.delimeter_option3)
    box_group2.addButton(self.delimeter_option4)
```

Comment: "Is this possible using Tkinter" - according to your code you are using PyQt - please explain.

Comment: You can add an entry to your GUI, then bind an event handler to the radio buttons, which, when the "Other" option is selected, shows that entry, and when another option is selected, rehides it.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include PyQt, I meant Tkinter or PyQt.

Comment: Well, you forgot to include PyQt, not Tkinter, and it doesn't make sense to include Tkinter because your code is clearly using PyQt

Comment: Do you mean if it's not possible to do such a thing in PyQt5 you would be willing to switch to Tkinter if it's possible there ?

Comment: At this point, I think it would make more sense to do it in PyQt since my radio buttons are from PyQt at the moment.

Comment: no -it is possible, of course, but it is not "ready" in either toolkit: you have to bind an event to your radio button, so that when "other" is selected, you enable and display a text entry for the user to type. You have to code that, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an entry to your layout. Then bind an event handler to the "Other" radio button's [`toggled`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#toggled) signal. The handler function will receive one argument, `checked`, which is a boolean and is True when the radio button is checked, and False when it isn't. Based on that, you can show or hide the entry, by calling it's `show` and `hide` methods, respectively. Here is a sample code:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Radio button demo")

        self.mainWid = QWidget(self)
        self.mainLay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.mainWid.setLayout(self.mainLay)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainWid)
        
        self.radioSemicolon = QRadioButton(",", self.mainWid)
        self.mainLay.addWidget(self.radioSemicolon)
        
        self.radioOther = QRadioButton("Other", self.mainWid)
        self.radioOther.toggled.connect(self.showHideOtherEntry)
        self.mainLay.addWidget(self.radioOther)
        
        self.radiosGroup = QButtonGroup(self)
        self.radiosGroup.addButton(self.radioSemicolon)
        self.radiosGroup.addButton(self.radioOther)
        
        self.otherEntry = QLineEdit(self.mainWid)
        self.otherEntry.setPlaceholderText("Enter other delimiter")
        self.mainLay.addWidget(self.otherEntry)
        self.otherEntry.hide()
        
    def showHideOtherEntry(self, clicked):
        if clicked:
            self.otherEntry.show()
        else:
            self.otherEntry.hide()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    app.exec_()
```