# Radio group with inline text edit fields?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I think the easiest way to ask this question is to simply show a Microsoft Paint mockup of what I'm trying to accomplish (see below).

I'm trying to create a widget that allows the user to (effectively) customize a database query that happens in the background. Most of the customizations can be done through simple checkboxes and radio buttons, but two of them seem to make the most sense to use radio buttons with text fields inside of them. The image below shows my idea for how to allow the user to select files described by the database in terms of their sizes: no size constraint, specify maximum size, minimum size, or a range of sizes.

[image]

I feel like this should be doable, but my searches aren't bearing much fruit. For example, [this related question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67825354/how-do-i-create-a-radio-button-that-accept-user-input-text) show a neat approach for one specific situation, but I don't know how much sense it makes in my situation. So, does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: That answer to that question is pretty close to what you could do here, my question is wouldn't it be better to use a spin box since you are dealing primarily with integers?

Comment: Perhaps a spin box might be suitable for this one, but as I mentioned, there are two categories like this. The other one isn't so nice -- it's not a single integer or range of integers. I chose the file size example because it was more straightforward.

Comment: got it.  So what is your question?  Are you having trouble with the layout or the logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really difficult to create this widget, it's just a combination of *QRadioButtons*, *QLabels*, *QLineEdits*, using a few of the basic *Layouts* notions.

In the example below, I used `QHBoxLayouts` to create the `QRadioButtons` texts, and display `QLineEdits` between the labels. I used a single `QGridLayout` to group all the Radio Buttons and their following Texts and Line Edits together.

By using a `QVBoxLayout`, I grouped the Grid Layout and the `QPushButton`, so you can extract information from the current selected option.

The application's output uses a `QMessageBox` to inform the user about the current result.

I didn't used a Spin Box to certify that the user types only integers inside the Line Edits. Instead, I used a `try-except` block to prevent any errors when calling the built-in `int()` function. However, using a Spin Box should be the right aproach.

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QGridLayout, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QMessageBox
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QRadioButton, QButtonGroup, QLineEdit, QPushButton

class Form(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.maximumSizeOnly = QLineEdit()
        self.betweenMinimum = QLineEdit()
        self.betweenMaximum = QLineEdit()
        self.minimumSizeOnly = QLineEdit()

        # magic's method logic
        self.lineEdits = [[], [self.maximumSizeOnly], [self.betweenMinimum, self.betweenMaximum], [self.minimumSizeOnly]]

        self.option1 = QRadioButton("")
        self.option2 = QRadioButton("")
        self.option3 = QRadioButton("")
        self.option4 = QRadioButton("")

        self.applyButton = QPushButton("Apply")
        self.applyButton.clicked.connect(self.apply)

        grid = QGridLayout()
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()

        self.setLayout(vbox)

        grid.addWidget(self.option1, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.option2, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.option3, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.option4, 3, 0)

        grid.addWidget(QLabel("Any Size"), 0, 1)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(QLabel("Maximum Size: "))
        hbox.addWidget(self.maximumSizeOnly)
        grid.addLayout(hbox, 1, 1)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(QLabel("Between "))
        hbox.addWidget(self.betweenMinimum)
        hbox.addWidget(QLabel(" and "))
        hbox.addWidget(self.betweenMaximum)
        grid.addLayout(hbox, 2, 1)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(QLabel("Minimum Size: "))
        hbox.addWidget(self.minimumSizeOnly)
        grid.addLayout(hbox, 3, 1)

        vbox.addLayout(grid)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.applyButton)
        hbox.addStretch(1)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)

        self.maximumSizeOnly.setEnabled(False)
        self.betweenMinimum.setEnabled(False)
        self.betweenMaximum.setEnabled(False)
        self.minimumSizeOnly.setEnabled(False)

        # Each ID is bound to self.lineEdits list.
        self.bGroup = QButtonGroup()
        self.bGroup.addButton(self.option1, 0)
        self.bGroup.addButton(self.option2, 1)
        self.bGroup.addButton(self.option3, 2)
        self.bGroup.addButton(self.option4, 3)

        self.bGroup.buttonToggled.connect(self.magic)

    def magic(self, button, down):
        index = self.bGroup.id(button)
        lineEdits = self.lineEdits[index]

        if (down):
            for le in lineEdits:
                le.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            for le in lineEdits:
                le.setEnabled(False)
                le.setText('')

    def apply(self):
        index = self.bGroup.checkedId()
        text = ''

        if (index == 0):
            text = 'Any Size set.'
        elif (index == 1):
            le = self.lineEdits[1][0]

            try:
                text = 'Maximum Size: %d' % (int(le.text()))
            except:
                text = 'Maximum Size: Undefined'

        elif (index == 2):
            leMin = self.lineEdits[2][0]
            leMax = self.lineEdits[2][1]

            try:
                text = 'Size Between: [%d, %d]' % (int(leMin.text()), int(leMax.text()))
            except:
                text = 'Size Between: Undefined'

        elif (index == 3):
            le = self.lineEdits[3][0]

            try:
                text = 'Minimum Size: %d' % (int(le.text()))
            except:
                text = 'Minimum Size: Undefined'
        else:
            dialog = QMessageBox()
            dialog.setWindowTitle('Error')
            dialog.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
            dialog.setText('No option is selected.')
            dialog.exec_()
            return

        dialog = QMessageBox()
        dialog.setWindowTitle('Success')
        dialog.setIcon(QMessageBox.NoIcon)
        dialog.setText(text)
        dialog.exec_()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Syzygy\'s Answer')

        self.form = Form()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.form)
        self.setMinimumWidth(300)

def main():
    app = QApplication()
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The main idea of this example is to make only the *selected option's* `QLineEdits` enabled at a time. When the user selects another option, the enabled widgets are disabled, and the new `QLineEdits`, if any, are enabled.

When a `QLineEdit` is disabled, all content is lost, as I call `le.setText("")` inside `magic()` method.

Inside `apply()` method, I show how to retrieve the selected Radio Button and display the desired result using their bound Line Edits.

---

I use PySide2 instead of PyQt5, so before executing the script, change each `PySide2` occurrence to `PyQt5`. The rest of the script should remain the same as only a few *variables* and *methods names* should change from one module to another.